# Are there any estimates for cost of manufacturing second if first JWST fails?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

Weird question, but I was thinking about this: assuming first launch fails and JWST is destroyed/totally nonfunctional, are there any estimates how much would cost to produce another one with issues that hindered first fixed?

I wonder since I presume large part of the cost(10 billions) is the design, so would seem kind of wasteful to just do nothing if first launch fails. So I wonder if NASA ever did this calculation?

note: I know second launch can also fail, I am just curious about the cost estimation.

Comment: the cost would be... wait for it... *astronomical*

Comment: I suspect the answer is zero, meaning that Congress would not authorize building a second JWST. In hindsight, the operations concept, the requirements, the design, and the implementation were all deeply flawed; the proof is in the immense schedule delays and cost overruns. Trying to rebuild a second JWST would be the sunk cost fallacy on steroids.

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer:

I think it's incorrect to assume that a " large part of the cost(10 billions) is the design".

Note that a large if undetermined amount of the schedule slips and cost overruns are due to *workmanship issues* i.e. human error.  Check out this graph (highlights mine):

[image]

The graph is from [GAO-19-189](https://www.gao.gov/assets/700/697887.pdf) *JAMES WEBB
SPACE TELESCOPE
Opportunity Nears
to Provide Additional
Assurance That
Project Can Meet
New Cost and
Schedule
Commitments*

The report includes this sad litany of screw-ups:

> • In October 2015, the project reported that a piece of flight hardware
> for the sunshield’s mid-boom assembly was irreparably damaged
> during vacuum sealing in preparation for shipping. The damaged
> piece had to be remanufactured, which consumed 3 weeks of
> schedule reserve.
>
> • In April 2017, a contractor technician applied too much voltage and
> irreparably damaged the spacecraft’s pressure transducers,
> components of the propulsion system that help monitor spacecraft fuel
> levels. The transducers had to be replaced and reattached in a
> complicated welding process. At the same time, Northrop Grumman
> also addressed several challenges with integrating sunshield
> hardware. These issues combined took up another 1.25 months of
> schedule reserve.
>
> • In May 2017, some of the valves in the spacecraft propulsion system’s
> thruster modules were leaking beyond permissible levels. Northrop
> Grumman determined that the most likely cause was the use of an
> improper cleaning solution, and the thruster modules were returned to
> the vendor for investigation and refurbishment. Reattaching the
> refurbished modules was expected to be complete by February 2018,
> but was delayed by one month when a technician applied too much
> voltage to one of the components in a recently refurbished thruster
> module. NASA and Northrop Grumman reported that resolving the
> thruster module issue resulted in a 2-month delay to the project’s
> overall schedule.
>
> • In October 2017, when conducting folding and deployment exercises
> on the sunshield, Northrop Grumman discovered several tears in the
> sunshield membrane layers. According to program officials, a
> workmanship error contributed to the tears. The tears resulted in
> another 2-month delay to the project’s overall schedule.

If they built another one, would they have the same error level? I see no reason to assume otherwise.

These GAO reports are interesting, if saddening, reading. Google up some of them and have a read; you'll see that it's man-hours that make up the majority of the cost.  Check out this graph of planned vs. actual workforce from [GAO-18-273](https://www.gao.gov/assets/700/690413.pdf) - the light blue is what the workforce was supposed to be.

[image]